# ARM assembly add of signed halfwords

Tags: assembly, arm

I am doing an audio mixer with 16 channels. Each channel is a signed halfword (short)
and I want to add them together and then divide by 16 so that the result is a signed halfword.
I can't seem to get my head around how to do this so that the signs are retained.
If I add 0x4fff and 0x6fff the result is negative but really want it to be a positive value in a 32bit word rather than a negative halfword. I am pretty sure sign extension needs to be used here but any suggestions would be welcome. I tried scaling each of the input values to 1/16 and then adding and that does work but then I lose resolution because each channel is reduced to 12bit

if I add all the channels and sign extend them before adding and then sign extend the added result followed by asr #4 shift to get back to 16bit result. Would that work?

Comment: Check out gbadev.org.  There is ARM sound mixer in assembler already coded for you over there if you need one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once your 2 values are loaded and added, the results are already within a 32 bit register.  Using an arithmetic shift for your divide should preserve the signed-ness of your final result. `ldrsh` will sign extend your negative values into 32-bits for you.

```
ldrsh r0, [r2], #4
ldrsh r1, [r2], #4
add r0, r0, r1
mov r0, r0, asr #4
```

Or something similar to that.  The final shift can also be combined with another op-code pretty easily.